# Which data structure contains of one parent node and many child nodes

Tags: data-structures

I like to represent the following numbers in a data structure, like in trees or list but with one parent node and possibly many child nodes

> 1.3.1.1.0
>
> 1.3.1.1.1
>
> 1.3.1.1.2
>
> 1.3.1.2.0
>
> 1.3.1.2.1
>
> 1.3.1.3.0
>
> ...

Which data structure allow me to store and search the given values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a trie? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Semantically it's like a BST-based/hashtable-based set (can check for presence/absence of a string, can enumerate all contained strings), but has different lookup costs (based on the length of the sought item, instead of the number contained items).

They are especially handy when you need to group/retrieve items by a common prefix (phone/SMS autocomplete could use a data structure like this).